# Implement service spring whith MuleESB

Tags: mule

I have a component that use a service spring, this spring service use a tiers validator. I defined a Interface with boolean isValide(String value), Can'I implement the Interface with MuleESB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somethink like

```
@Autowired
    private MuleContext muleContext;

    @Override
    public boolean isValide(String arg0) {

        try {

            MuleClient muleClient = new MuleClient(muleContext);

        } catch (MuleException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
```

like in http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/32X/Hello+World+Example